# How to add Primary Key from Existing table in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Now i am working in SQLite database. I want to add primary key from my existing table. But i couldn't add the primary key in existing table and i have deleted all the records in the old table. So how can i add the primary key from existing table in SQLite?

Here my query is,

```
        alter table studetails add constraint pk primary key (rollno).
```

I have used that above query, but it shown error.  Is it possible?, if yes, please guide me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot according to SQLite's syntax perform this operation. In general it seems strange to add a primary key to an existing table. This should be done using the create table statement (you can also add an index by create index).

Br
Anders

[Alter table in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#alter-table-stmt)
[Create table in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#create-table-stmt)